# JavaFX 8 Duplicate children after getChildren().clear()

Tags: java, javafx

Im clearing the Gridpane of all children, then adding children again to the Gridpane yet it says that there are duplicates.

```
public void render(){
    boardPane.getChildren().clear();
    for(int x = 0; x < xSize; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < ySize; y++){
            boardPane.add(blockBoard[x][y], x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

blockBoard[x][y] contains objects that are replaced every render cycle.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"    
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: 
duplicate children added:     parent = Grid hgap=0.0, vgap=0.0,
alignment=TOP_LEFT
at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Parent.java:454)
at   com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.add
(VetoableListDecorator.java:206)
at javafx.scene.layout.GridPane.add(GridPane.java:965)
at tetris.Game.render(Game.java:121)
```

Comment: Are you sure `blockBoard` itself doesn't contain duplicates?

Comment: an array can have duplicates as well??? They contain Tile Objects for example blockBoard[x][y] = new Tile(); there are a lot of new Tile(); objects in the array.

Comment: Yes. Nothing prevents you from adding the same object twice to an array.

Comment: but why would it be a problem if i have thousand same new Tile() objects in the array, javafx shouldnt be against adding them as long as theyre in different gridpane coordinates? Im always giving a different coordinate (x, y) in the forloop

Comment: Did you perhaps overwrite `equals` for `Tile`?

Comment: You're doing something strange somewhere: either in the creation of the array or in the definition of the `Tile` class. You probably need to post a [MCVE] if you want help fully figuring out what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

that is because of this code from method onProposedChange of Parent Class

```
childSet.addAll(newNodes);
if (childSet.size() != newLength) {
   throw new IllegalArgumentException(
       constructExceptionMessage(
           "duplicate children added", null));
}
```

So you just should remove duplicate nodes from blockBoard.
Probably you should use TableView for this stuff.

Comment: TableView will allow me to add duplicate nodes?

Comment: adding boardPane.getChildren.remove(blockBoard[x][y]) resolved this even though i cleared the whole grid it still requires me to specifically remove the exact object. Clear seems to leave something still behind from the last render cycle.

Comment: "TableView will allow me to add duplicate nodes?"
No it is still child of Parent Class. But you can add duplicate data and leave node managenent to TableView.